# Determine application framework version in library C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-standard, appsettings

I have a library which is .NET standard version. This library will be used both .NET app and .NET Core apps. I want to use `IConfiguration` for .NET Core apps in my library but .NET apps throw an exception.

I need to check version or determine the application if .NET Core or .NET framework? I have tried get `appsettings.json` file to determine app type but getting root path different both .NET and .NET Core apps.

When I tried to get framework version of app it gives me library's version.

How can I distinguish which type of application it is? How can I achieve this?

Comment: .NET 5 and 6 are .NET *Core* 5 and 6. Are you referring to .NET Framework perhaps? You can use .NET's Configuration, Logging and Dependency Injection in .NET Framework apps as well by installing the NuGet packages

Comment: In any case, the runtime version won't help you at all. Where will your library load its config settings from if Configuration isn't set up? `appsettings.json` isn't some kind of special file. It's just a JSON file that's loaded by the Configuration middleware. You could specify numerous other files, in multiple locations, with different formats. Or even load settings from databases. You could easily remove that file too. Without the Configuration middleware, the `appsettings.json` file won't be loaded at all

Comment: Can you post some example code that throws when used in .NETFramework but fine with .NET Core? I think you're running into the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Libraries have no business accessing configuration this way, that's the application's job. Have it supply you with the configuration you need, as strongly typed data; how the application gets it is the application's problem. And while you *can* use `IConfiguration` to get that data passed in, that is a very specific and very weak abstraction that doesn't make it clear what kind of configuration your classes need.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to solve your problem:

- try to use more common parameters for your methods that requires string's, int's or custom classes instead. Is it really necessary to add a framework specific class or function or is there a better option?
- You can use a [multi-target configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/nuget/create-packages/multiple-target-frameworks-project-file) for your library which then requires #if NET45 and #elif NETSTANDARD2_0 code everywhere you have to use different logic for different frameworks. This could lead to not very well readable code.
- Use two libraries, one for .NET Core apps (e.g. based on .NET Standard 2.1) and the other for .NET Framework (e.g. .NET FW 4.8). The .cs files from the .NET Standard library can then also be used in the .NET 4.8 library (if compatible features have been used). The .cs files can be selected e.g. in VS via "context menu > add existing element". When confirming the selected file(s), expand the dropdown option under "Add" and select "Add as Link". This way the file only needs to be maintained once (changes are applied in both libraries). Framework-specific files can then be added individually in the respective library, not as a link. [Here's](https://jeremybytes.blogspot.com/2019/07/linking-files-in-visual-studio.html) a good article about it.

These are just some examples, there might be of course other or better solutions to it.

Personally I would try to use independent arguments for my methods, if this is not possible I prefer the custom library solution for each framework version.